# Scrape webpage that requires md5 hash as a parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, md5

I am trying to scrape the data from the below link, in a c# console app:
https://www.eex-transparency.com/homepage/power/germany/production/availability/non-usability

Using the developer tools in chrome I can see that its possible to get a json response, the url to get this is:
https://www.eex-transparency.com/dsp/tem-12?country=de&expires=1454345128&md5=TRhtJei_go4ueLeekBc8yw

the website uses this js file (https://www.eex-transparency.com/assets/js/tpe-website.js) to generate the expires and md5 hash key. I think I've figured out that the expires value is a unix datetime. I have never used javascript before so finding it hard to figure out how they construct the md5.

The Javascript that generates these code is:

```
generateCryptedParams=function(url,clientIP)
{
    var cryptedParams,md5,md5Encoded,md5WithoutSpeciaChars,parser,timePoint,urlPath;

return timePoint=moment().tz("Europe/Berlin").add(1,"minute").unix(),
                 parser=document.createElement("a"),
                 parser.href=url,
                 urlPath=parser.pathname,
                 "/"!==urlPath[0]&&(urlPath="/"+urlPath),
                 md5=CryptoJS.MD5(urlPath+timePoint+clientIP+" zYeHzBomGdgV"),
                 md5Encoded=md5.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64),
                 md5WithoutSpeciaChars=replaceSpecialChars(md5Encoded),
                 cryptedParams={"expires":timePoint,"md5":md5WithoutSpeciaChars}
}

replaceSpecialChars=function(str)
{
var key,specialChars,value;
specialChars={"=":"","\\+":"-","/":"_","%":"_"};
for(key in specialChars)
    value=specialChars[key],
     str=str.replace(new RegExp(key,"g"),value);

return str
}
```

As i said I think I'm comfortable with the timepoint part but the md5 is confusing me. Below is my C# code to replicate their but when I pass the md5 hash their site returns a 403 Forbidden error.

```
    public Tuple<string, Int32> GenerateCrypto(string url, string ipAddress)
    {
        string cetId = "Central European Standard Time";
        TimeZoneInfo cetZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(cetId);
        var CETDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, cetZone);
        //Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(CETDateTime.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
        Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1).Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;


        url = url.Split('/')[3];
        var md5 = CipherUtility.GenerateMd5(url + unixTimestamp + ipAddress + " zYeHzBomGdgV");
        var md5Encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(md5));
        var md5withoutSpecialCharts = replaceSpecialChars(md5Encoded);
        md5withoutSpecialCharts = md5withoutSpecialCharts.Substring(0, 22);
        return new Tuple<string, Int32>(md5withoutSpecialCharts, unixTimestamp);
    }
```

Comment: Just pay someone to reverse engineer the code for you (such work is generally gray zone at best from laws point of view, but)... Not sure why you expect SO to to that for you. If you have some more specific question - please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: Why you want to know how they construct MD5 hash?? What code are you using to scrape webpage? show us the code where MD5 hash is required? Generally MD5 hash is generated against content of webpage and is generally used to verfiy the content of webpage \ any document.....In C# you can use Cyrptography namespace to generate MD5 hash

Comment: Are you able to provide the exact JavaScript used to generate the MD5?

Comment: @Elias Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Yes I did. If I remember correctly the reason I couldn't match the MD5 hash was because they concatenate a number to the unit date time before they produce the hash. If you are having the same issue I can look at my source code. I should change this post to answered.

Comment: @Elias nice one, cheers. I had a go at it myself, shortly after commenting here, and got some useful data: http://energynumbers.info/germanys-offshore-wind-capacity-factors . I'd be interested to see what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was that I needed to concatenate a const string to all the elements before hashing it.